# Pass List<IntPtr>* to EnumWindows' lParam in C#

Tags: c#, winapi, interop, marshalling, fixed

I'm trying to write a function which iterates over top level windows and puts them into a list if they fulfil a set of criteria. At the moment I can get this to work by adding the windows into a static `List<IntPtr> instances` variable, but I would like to instead pass a pointer to a list in the `EnumWindowsProc`'s `lParam` in order to avoid this static variable.

I think I have to use `fixed` to fix the list's position in memory, but I am unsure how to do this. I tried this to pass the list to my callback function:

```
unsafe
{
    fixed (void* dp = &instances)
    {
        WinApi.EnumWindows(new WinApi.EnumWindowsProc(FindPPWindows), dp);
    }
}
```

but I get

```
Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('System.Collections.GenericList<IntPtr>')
```

I'm newish to c# so I don't really know how to do this - or even if it's possible, I've read that marshalling a managed type containing references is impossible but I only need to fix it in memory and create a pointer to it, then cast the pointer back and use it. How can I make this work, if at all?

Comment: You cannot create a pointer to a class. The only thing you can do is to create a array, and pass the first item's pointer, `void* dp = &instancesArray` will point the first item. But you still have to keep somewhere the size of the array, and send a enought large array to contain all windows.

Answer (score 2):

You could call the EnumWindows function with an lambda expression. Then the EnumWindowsProc Callback would be inline and you can access to local variables:

```
List<IntPtr> list = new List<IntPtr>();            

WinApi.EnumWindows((hWnd, lParam) =>
{
      //check conditions
      list.Add(hWnd);

      return true;

}, IntPtr.Zero);
```

You could capsulate this inline call in an extra function, e.g.:

```
List<IntPtr> GetMatchingHWnds()
{
    List<IntPtr> list = new List<IntPtr>();            

    WinApi.EnumWindows((hWnd, lParam) =>
    {
          //check conditions
          list.Add(hWnd);

          return true;

    }, IntPtr.Zero);

    return list;        
}
```